# Run callback after running a job in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I use queue in Laravel, I want to know if there is any way to run some code after handling  the jobs. I mean, I want to save a something in the db after running a job. It is important to me knowing which job has run by scheduler. any idea?

Comment: why do not just do your stuffs at the end of the `handle` function of the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event) {
// $event->connectionName
// $event->job
// $event->job->payload()
});
```

[source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#job-events)

Comment: I think this works just for failed jobs,  am I right?

Comment: It should work for any job based on what's written in the first paragraph of the linked documentation

Comment: what if we have more than 1 job running? Will it call every time? I want it to run once all jobs have been completed. any idea??